# spring rabbitmq application: console or web

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

i have to develop an application in spring and rabbitmq. This is new for me and i dont have much experience at all.

Basically the app have to:

- constantly check the database and if there are some changes send a
  message to a determined queue.
- Listen for some queues and reply with some data.

So my questions is what would you choose to make this application, a console based app or a web based app. and why?

ps: sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: why is spring a requirement? could you write a stand alone java app that reads/writes to rabbit and interacts with DB? what would be the gain of making it a web app? doesn't seem like requests are coming in via http/soap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check database and send messages to rabbitmq queues and reply with some data, then I would recommend you to go for a console only application. You can run the application as a standalone service. Spring already has an integration with RabbitMQ.

We are already using Spring-RabbitMQ for doing some heavy calculations in our application, which is done by another application. So we run the calculation application as a standalone console application and this application listens to messages arriving in the Rabbit MQ.

A web application would be required if you want to monitor this process remotely. Like for e.g. you need to see what kind of messages where arrived and then reply according to input messages, and you need it all to be done remotely, you would need a web application. Otherwise keep it a simple console application. You can use build tools like Maven to test console applications also. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Whether you write it as a console app or a webapp will have little or no impact on how you actually do the database check and message sending. If that's what you're asking, it doesn't matter.

The choice of standalone vs. web application is influenced by other things, like how you'll be deploying the app, how familiar other developers--if there are others working with you--are with building and running standalone apps vs. webapps, and tool support for running and testing your app in development.

Personally, I think I'd choose a web application because the whole world is writing webapps, so there's a ton of support already built up for doing things in and with them, including building, testing, and deploying them. You tend to get better support for testing webapps from build tools like Maven and Gradle, though it seems like Gradle narrows or closes the gap on this. You also get a free remote interface with a webapp that's practically a universal language nowadays (HTTP) that will let you make the app available from anywhere pretty easily.